# Lazzy loading of Audio Thumbnails in GridView Android

Tags: android

I am working on Audio Player and i want to show album art in Grid View. In my Custom Adapter i have used following code.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row1, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = convertView;
        }


        // TODO replace findViewById by ViewHolder
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(mData.get(position).albumName);
        Bitmap image=null;
        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, mData.get(position).albumId);
        try {
            image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    context.getContentResolver(), albumArtUri);
            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 320, 320, true);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            image= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.adele);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ((ImageView) result.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(image);
        return result;
    }
```

The code is ok but due to lazy loading it is creating problem. Can anyone tell me solution?

Comment: What kind of problem is it creating?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed gallery of images in Custom GridView . I have used [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for image downloading and displaying . I found it is super easy because it is just One line of code to download image and display it into your ImageView.

Here is my getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
  
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null)
        {
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, null);
        }
        
      
        holder.pImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);
      
        holder.pTitle.setText(titlesForProducts[position]);
                       
       
        Picasso.with(context).load("Image Url").into(holder.pImage);
        return convertView;
  }
```

Most importantly this library uses automatic memory and disk caching.

Once you load your images with this library second time it load from cache that it has created so ,image loading becomes faster.

Give it a try . it take only few seconds.